# Firebase phone authentification in react ionic

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, capacitor

I am using firebase phone authentification for verification phone number in react ionic app.
It works perfectly on web version, but I got this error on iOS.

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error). wrapNativeSuper.js

This is my code.

```
import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app"
import { Capacitor } from "@capacitor/core"
import { getAuth, initializeAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence } from "firebase/auth"

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXX",
    authDomain: "XXX.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "XXX",
    storageBucket: "XXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXX",
    appId: "XXX",
    measurementId: "XXX"
  };


const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
let auth
export function getFirebaseAuth() {
  if (!auth) {
    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
      auth = initializeAuth(getApp(), { persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence })
    } else {
      auth = getAuth()
    }
  }
  return auth
}

export default  firebaseApp
```

And this is implement part.

```
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber, PhoneAuthProvider  } from "firebase/auth";
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getFirebaseAuth  } from "../firebaseInit";


...


const auth = getFirebaseAuth()

const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container", {
    size: "invisible",
},auth);
signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, `+81${phonenumber}`, recaptchaVerifier)
.then((confirmationResult) => {
     ...
})
```

I added the URL Types in XCode according to this tutorial.

[Set up reCAPTCHA verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth?hl=en&authuser=0&_gl=1*kdbuq2*_ga*MjAxODQ5MDMzNS4xNjg3MjUwMjQy*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4OTgxNzEzMC4zNi4xLjE2ODk4MTcxOTcuMC4wLjA.#set-up-recaptcha-verification)

Comment: May be you also need browserLocalPersistence and browserPopupRedirectResolver as well. I got an idea from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-dependencies#platform-specific_considerations

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample implementation of phone authentication using Firebase in a React Ionic app:

replace `"YOUR_API_KEY"`, `"YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN"`, and other placeholders in the `firebaseConfig` object with your actual Firebase project details.

Set up your Firebase configuration and initialize the Firebase app in a separate file, `firebaseInit.js:`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
  measurementId: "YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID",
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container", {
  size: "invisible",
});

export { auth, recaptchaVerifier };
```

create a component that handles phone authentication, `PhoneAuth.js:`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonButton } from "@ionic/react";
import { auth, recaptchaVerifier } from "../firebaseInit";

const PhoneAuth = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState("");
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);

  const handleSendCode = () => {
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, `+81${phoneNumber}`, recaptchaVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        setVerificationId(confirmationResult.verificationId);
        // The verification code will be sent to the user's phone
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error sending verification code:", error);
      });
  };

  const handleVerifyCode = () => {
    const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, credential)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // User is now signed in with their phone number
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error verifying code:", error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Phone Authentication</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <div>
          <input type="tel" value={phoneNumber} onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)} />
          <IonButton onClick={handleSendCode}>Send Verification Code</IonButton>
        </div>
        {verificationId && (
          <div>
            <input type="text" value={verificationCode} onChange={(e) => setVerificationCode(e.target.value)} />
            <IonButton onClick={handleVerifyCode}>Verify Code</IonButton>
          </div>
        )}
        <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default PhoneAuth;
```

main app component, use the PhoneAuth component:

```
import React from "react";
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from "@ionic/react";
import { IonReactRouter } from "@ionic/react-router";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import PhoneAuth from "./components/PhoneAuth";

const App = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/phone-auth" />} />
        <Route path="/phone-auth" component={PhoneAuth} />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);

export default App;
```

When the user enters their phone number and clicks "Send Verification Code," the code will be sent to their phone. They can then enter the verification code and click "Verify Code" to complete the authentication process.